# UIPopover Not Showing, Causing Crash

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uitableview, uipopovercontroller

I'm using this code to show a popover from the toolbar of the detail view of a split view controller.

```
- (IBAction)showBookmarksMenu:(id)sender
{
    BookmarksViewController* content = [[BookmarksViewController alloc] init];//UITableViewController
    UIPopoverController* aPopover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:content];
    aPopover.delegate = self;
    [content release];

    // Store the popover in a custom property for later use.
    self.popoverController = aPopover;
    [aPopover release];

    [self.popoverController presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:sender permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
}
```

Getting this crash:

```
2011-08-16 23:59:55.730 Codes[3646:707] -[DetailViewControlleriPad showBookmarksMenu]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x191220
2011-08-16 23:59:55.757 Codes[3646:707] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[DetailViewControlleriPad showBookmarksMenu]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x191220'
```

Comment: try without releasing apopover

Comment: How are you calling showBookmarksMenu?

Comment: That method is linked in IB with a UIBarButtonItem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `showBookmarksMenu:` method is being called on `DetailViewControlleriPad`, whereas it should be called on the class which implements it.

Ensure that the method is properly hooked in IB.

Comment: So how can I fix this? Bookmarks view controller is just a static table view.

Comment: The problem is not with `BookmarksViewController`. In which class do you have `showBookMarksMenu`?

Comment: Is it present in DetailViewControlleriPad.h ?

Comment: No, it's in the .m.  It's hooked up with a UIBarButtonItem in IB that I want to show the bookmarks popover when clicked.

Comment: Can you try adding showBookmarksMenu's declaration to the .h file?

Comment: I have it in then.h also. Sorry I misunderstood you earlier.

Comment: Try disconnecting and reconnecting the method to the UIBarButtonItem in IB.

Comment: Not sure then. It seems to be an issue with IB hooks.

Comment: You're right. Recconecting in IB worked.  But I now get this error after a second. `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: '-[UIPopoverController dealloc] reached while popover is still visible.'`

Comment: Try commenting out [aPopover release];.  What happens then?

Comment: Completely different issue. Search for this error string and you will find many solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Your showBookmarksMenu: method is not found by the class and that's why it is crashing your application. Check your source code and try again. Have a happy coding. :)